# HTTPS using Retrofit and OkHttp Handshake failed

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to learn how to use Retrofit and OkHttp with HTTPS.
From what I've read I either need to have the certificate in my `raw` folder or get it using this command `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect api.****.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > gtux.cert`. Where do I run the above-mentioned command?
In my case I already have the `.cer` file in `raw` folder (it was given to me). According to [this](https://gist.github.com/erikcaffrey/10af1cc0b99a54f5b9a8a7614cca6f0a) gist, my code looks like the following:

```
    public class SelfSignInClient {

    private Context context;

    public SelfSignInClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Certificate certificate = getCertificate();
        KeyStore keyStore = createKeyStoreTrustedCAs(certificate);
        TrustManagerFactory managerFactory = createTrustManagerCAs(keyStore);
        SSLContext sslContext = createSSLSocketFactory(managerFactory);

        okHttpClient.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        okHttpClient.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return hostname.equals("https://dev.api.***.com:443");
            }
        });

        // If you need an Interceptor to add some header
        //okHttpClient.addInterceptor();
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        return okHttpClient.build();
    }

    // creating an SSLSocketFactory that uses our TrustManager
    private SSLContext createSSLSocketFactory(TrustManagerFactory managerFactory) {
        final String PROTOCOL = "TLS";
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert sslContext != null;
            sslContext.init(null, managerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

    // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    private TrustManagerFactory createTrustManagerCAs(KeyStore keyStore) {
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory managerFactory = null;
        try {
            managerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert managerFactory != null;
            managerFactory.init(keyStore);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return managerFactory;
    }

    // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    private KeyStore createKeyStoreTrustedCAs(Certificate certificate) {
        final String ALIAS_CA = "ca";
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert keyStore != null;
            keyStore.load(null, null);
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(ALIAS_CA, certificate);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    // creating a Certificate
    private Certificate getCertificate() {
        Certificate certificate = null;
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = loadCertificateAuthorityFromResources();
        InputStream inputStream = getCAFromResources();
        try {
            certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return certificate;
    }

    // loading CAs from an InputStream
    private CertificateFactory loadCertificateAuthorityFromResources() {
        final String CERT_TYPE = "X.509";
        InputStream certificateAuthority = getCAFromResources();
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = null;
        try {
            certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance(CERT_TYPE);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            assert certificateFactory != null;
            certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateAuthority);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                certificateAuthority.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return certificateFactory;
    }

    // loading CAs from Resources
    // save your certificate.crt on raw package in your resources
    private InputStream getCAFromResources() {
        return context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);
    }
}
```

And then, my REST Client:

```
private static final String BASE_URL = "***";
ApiService mApiService;

public RestClient() {
    SelfSignInClient selfSignInClient = new SelfSignInClient(App.getContext());
    OkHttpClient okClient;
    okClient = selfSignInClient.getOkHttpClient();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Peem.class, new PeemDeserializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory());
    Retrofit retrofit;
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()))
            .client(okClient)
            .build();

    this.mApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

}
```

But, whenever I try to run, I get this exception:

> 04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:241)
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:198)
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:174)
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
>   04-19 08:26:13.666 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   04-19 08:26:13.667 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:33)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:120)
>   04-19 08:26:13.668 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>   04-19 08:26:13.669 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   04-19 08:26:13.669 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   04-19 08:26:13.669 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   04-19 08:26:13.670 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
>   04-19 08:26:13.670 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:        ... 29 more
>   04-19 08:26:13.671 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xac0d93c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   04-19 08:26:13.671 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:192 0x9d254196:0x00000000)
>   04-19 08:26:13.671 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   04-19 08:26:13.671 3932-3932/com.peems.itcrowd W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)

**EDIT:**
When I try to run `echo -n | openssl s_client -connect api.****.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > gtux.cert` in CMD I get this response `Loading 'screen' into random state -'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and I have a .cert file which is 0kb.